# Proper media query for iphone 11?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iphone, responsive

simply as the title states:

What is the actual correct media query for responsive design for a iphone 11?

Im using the ***Mobile Simulator*** chrome extension that suggest its 414x896 resolution however it doesnt seem to work.

Having a problem where my portfolio looks good on basically every other phone then my Iphone 11.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Media queries are usually based on the available width in pixels, not a specific phone. Please clarify *how* your layout fails on an iPhone 11.

Comment: Hey Chris! Thanks for replying

Problem i have is a simple <p> tag thats abit too far down. Tried using a simple `margin-bottom: 16rem !important;` but for some reason its not moving. Its moving in my preview but still doesnt display when im on my phone.

Comment: Are you positive your phone is using the updated stylesheet? You might have to go into Safari's settings and clear chache and browsing data (or install the Firefox app instead and simply hold down the refresh icon)